# backgroundPosition in javasctipt is not working

Tags: javascript, css, background, position, background-position

Basically I did a rollover in css but i want it in javascript instead. Also I want,once my page is loaded one of the pictures would be automatically selected. I tried this code for that but its not working.. any ideas? for some reason its not calling the function. ps: the id is called clicked3 as well in my html

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onLoad=function(){
clicked3();
}

function clicked3(){
document.getElementById("clicked3").style.backgroundPosition = "-198px top";
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real reason your code isn't working is because you're assigning your function to a non-existent event handler `onLoad`. `window.onload` is the correct syntax, notice it's all lower case.

http://jsfiddle.net/9Kh8f/3/

Answer (score 1):

Do yourself a favor and use a javascript library, such as jQuery...

1) Javascript is case sensitive, so window.onLoad isn't the same as window.onload (correct sintax)

2) If your image is exactly 198px wide (you're hiding the image), you may have forgot to add `background-repeat:no-repeat;` in your css, making you see a copy of that image

Anyway, your sintax for changing background position is correct, see it in action here:

http://jsfiddle.net/zszB4/

Answer (score -1):

You dont need the window.onload=function.. you can just call...

```
window.onload=clicked3();
```

Working demo here for you :)

http://jsfiddle.net/9Kh8f/

Comment: `window.onload=clicked3();` sets the onload event to fire whatever the return value is from the clicked3 function. It would effectively be the same as using `window.onload=document.getElementById("clicked3").style.backgroundPosition="-198px top";`

Comment: Why have I been voted down for this? This is a working solution to the posters question? With this he can add it onto button clicks and many such others by removing the window.onLoad.

Comment: The reason it "worked" was because you called the function immediately, it wasn't a proper solution. Your `window.onLoad` was never fired because `a)` it was wrapped in an onload event itself and `b)` `onLoad` is not the right methods `onload` is.

Comment: His posted code showed that he wanted it called immediately? and apologies for the onload typo, however if you refer to the jsfiddle its correct.

Comment: Your code works but it's only because you wrapped it in a MooTools onload event, you're then immediately calling the clicked3 function whilst assigning the return value (undefined in this case) to a non existent property of the window object (`onLoad`).

Comment: OriginalSyn was right. I firstly tried your solution and didn't work